# A geometric problem

Tags: geometry

A friend asked me two days ago showing this question.

He said that to me it would be very easy. He was wrong, I cannot solve it so far.

Prove that internal bisectors of angles in the four vertices of a quadrilateral determine by intersection four points which are common points to the same circle (see figure attached to prevent probable deficiencies in English).

[image]

Comment: Denote the angles of the quadrilateral by A,B,C,D, and the angles in the small quadrilateral by P,Q,R,S. What is P in terms of A,B,C,D? What about R? What would be the relation between them if PQRS was cyclic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$ \angle DSC = \pi - \frac{1}{2} (\angle ADC +\angle BCD ) $$

$$ \angle AQB = \pi - \frac{1}{2} (\angle BAD +\angle ABC ) $$

Hence $$ \angle DSC +\angle AQB = \pi $$

Comment: Amazing how math things can be either very easy or impossible, according to people involved. Thank you.